# How to use values from .properties file in log4j.xml file in Java

Tags: xml, logging, properties, log4j

I want to use a value from .properties file in my log4j.xml file.
Actually wanna set value of a parameter in log4j.xml file;

Like there is some PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring
What can I use in log4j.xml ??
Any sort of guide or suggestion would be appreciable.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but hopefully someone stumbling onto this question finds the following useful.  Log4j supports property substitution, so you can use a value stored in a properties or ini file in your log4j XML configuration file.  See the prefix section from Apache's [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution).

I've performed property substitution using an .ini file.  You should be able to easily do the same thing with a .properties file as well.  Here's how you could dynamically set the path for your log file using a properties/ini value:

```
//for an .ini file using org.ini4j.Wini
ini = new Wini(new File(args[0]));
System.setProperty("log_dir", ini.get("yourSubHeader", "yourPropertyName"));

//for a .properties file
prop.load(input); //using a FileInputStream
System.setProperty("log_dir", prop.getProperty("yourPropertyName"));
```

Once you've set a system property, you can use the sys prefix to retrieve this value in your XML config file via something like the following:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path" >${sys:log_dir}</Property>
    <!-- other properties here -->
</Properties>
```

Hopefully this proves helpful to anyone wondering the same question.